# Microsoft Outlook - Create a hyperlink to send specific emails

Tags: outlook

I am trying to create a hyperlink in my email to request for feedback.

So i would provide button as of below and when they click either of them, it will automatically send an email back to me (fixed), with variable subject (good, neutral, not good) and content(A1 is good, A1 is neutral, A1 is not good).

1) Good
2) Neutral
3) Not Good

Anyone has idea on this? Sorry as I am not very clear on the functions available in outlook. Looking forward for any similar suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you would like to create polls in email messages and review the results. If so, you can refer to the following link:

[Create polls in email messages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-polls-in-email-messages-and-review-the-results-4d10e079-8ea1-489a-a79c-18cb71ae12dd?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[Using-voting-buttons-email](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/using-voting-buttons-email/)

However, I'm not sure if you want to implement it by using code mode e.g. VBA/C#?

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for your feedback. Actually is less of voting. I would require a single click button in email maybe in VBA or C# if possible, to lead to another email with fixed subject and content. I will send the email to 100 users with 100 similar contents with a different unique ID. I would like them to click on the email, to reply (good, neutral, bad) with the uniqie ID tied to it. Do you have any idea about this?